# Data mining for categorical variables that correspond to modes of a continuous variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, data-mining, data-preprocessing, mode

Is there a good method or test to find categorical variables associated with modes of a continuous variable?

Take the velocity of a car as an example. You would expect there to be at least two modes in the data (one for reverse and one for forward), but you could have more (park, 1st gear, 2nd gear, etc.). Let's say we are interested in subsetting the velocity based on the categorical variable such as reverse/forward/gear before doing any modeling and we know the variable indicating gear is present in the data set, but the variable name is unintuitive (e.g., 'X149') and it is mixed among hundreds of other categorical variables (my data is about as ugly as it gets).

Is there a good method to pick the correct categorical variable for subsetting the continuous variable? I've tried linear regression with forward/back/bidirectional stepping but the results are less than desirable and yield different answers depending on the directions chosen (yes I know about the pitfalls of this method but I wasn't sure what else to try).

Comment: Can you be clearer about what the task you are trying to accomplish actually is?  With the car analogy, are you trying to identify the categorical variable that best matches the speed categories present in the data?  My first thought (if a simple regression wasn't helping) was maybe you could model the continuous variable as a mixture of distributions then find the relationships of the categorical variables with the predicted components, but since I don't fully understand the question I don't know if that would be helpful.

Comment: Also, if you're just looking for a single categorical explanatory variable why would you use stepwise regression instead of just trying them all and finding the variable that best explains the outcome?

Comment: Yes, for this analogy I'm looking for the categorical variable that best matches the speed categories present in the data. It is desirable to leave the possibility open for more than one categorical variable to explain the mode/generating distribution of the continuous variable. 

In the data I'm actually working with I've found at least one case where the continuous data is a mixture of three distributions where the generating distribution is indicated by a combination of two binary variables (two out of four of those combinations result in the same distribution).

Comment: In what way have you tried regression -- have you preserved the categorical nature of the predictor levels?  I would think that (or, alternately put, ANOVA) would be your best bet.

Comment: I believe I have preserved the categorical nature of the levels. Thus far I've performed stepwise regression (forward/backward/bidirectional) in R using the `step()` function in R with the default value of `k=2`. The data used during this process is contained in a data table object with the first column being a numeric type (response variable) and all other columns being factor type (potential response variables). R should automatically make a model matrix from this data with the appropriate number of dummy variables for each factor in the data table.

Comment: In that case could you expand upon "the results are less than desirable."

Comment: "Less than desirable" for me means forward stepping almost always leads to no variables being selected (y ~ 1) and back stepping typically results in way too many variables being selected.